# Read streamed response as it comes in

Tags: javascript, browser, stream, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to start a long-running (10-30 seconds) job on our server and monitor progress on it *without* closing the connection. Basically, I upload a file, and pipe the progress back to the client delimited by newlines. Here's an example response (each newline is delayed by a couple milliseconds):

```
01
23
48
60
73
87
96
```

I was able to get this working using the experimental [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) and [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder) apis, but I'm looking for a more browser-compatible way. Here's my code:

```
fetch('/thing/').then(r => {
  let reader = r.body.getReader('byob')

  const doIt = () => {
    reader.read().then(({done, value}) => {
      value = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value)

      if (done) {
        clearInterval(interval)
      }

      if (value) {
        console.log(`${value}% done`)
      }
    })
  }

  const interval = setInterval(doIt, 10)
})
```

I've tried setting responseType on an XMLHttpRequest to `blob` and `arraybuffer`, checking the response every millisecond, but wasn't able to get either to stream; it would just print out the complete response on completion.

Comment: Why not WebSockets? (Socket.io)

Comment: I don't want to build any extra infrastructure; this is sort of a one-off thing in an existing project. That's why I'm avoiding long-polling as well.

Comment: Maybe [server-sent event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)? or [xhr's progress monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress)?

Comment: Server sent events look promising, I may look into them, although they don't meet the browser compatibility requirement (no edge/IE support). I had tried the progress monitor, but I missed the note that says to add the handlers before calling `open`, which I did not do. I'll give this a try today.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit more, and I think I'm going to go with the solution in my original question, as it has comparable browser compatibility with SSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
function monitorServerSentEvents(url, opts, onProgress) {
  const headers = {'Content-Type': false, 'Accept': false}

  return fetch(url, {headers, ...opts}).then(res => {
    const reader = res.body.getReader('byob')

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ;(function readProgress() {
        reader.read()
          .catch(reject)
          .then(({done, value}) => {
            if (done) {
              resolve()
            }

            if (!value) {
              return
            }

            const decoder = (new TextDecoder("utf-8"))
            const progress = decoder.decode(value).trim().split('\n')

            progress.forEach(onProgress)

            setTimeout(readProgress, 50)
          })
      }())
    })
  })
}
```

This only works on browser that support [ReadableStream.getReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader).